# How to use 'mv' command to move files except those in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, mv

I am wondering - how can I move all the files in a directory except those files in a specific directory (as 'mv' does not have a '--exclude' option)?

Comment: check out this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/command-line-mv-exclusion-list

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Lets's assume the dir structure is like,

```
|parent
    |--child1
    |--child2
    |--grandChild1
    |--grandChild2
    |--grandChild3
    |--grandChild4
    |--grandChild5
    |--grandChild6
```

And we need to move files so that it would appear like,

```
|parent
    |--child1
    |   |--grandChild1
    |   |--grandChild2
    |   |--grandChild3
    |   |--grandChild4
    |   |--grandChild5
    |   |--grandChild6
    |--child2
```

In this case, you need to exclude two directories `child1` and `child2`, and move rest of the directories in to `child1` directory.

use,

```
mv !(child1|child2) child1
```

This will move all of rest of the directories into `child1` directory.

Comment: Tip: Note however that using this pattern relies on `extglob`. You can enable it using `shopt -s extglob` (If you want `extended globs` to be turned on by default you can add `shopt -s extglob` to .bashrc)

Comment: I keep getting `-bash: !: event not found` when trying to do this command.

Comment: Derp, just realized the comment above is required for bash.

Comment: How can this be forced? when there are no other directories other than the ones ignored? ```mv -f``` does not seem to work. I've temp solved it by creating a temp directory so there are three dirs in total, then moving all directories, then removing the temp dir. ugly!

Comment: Be careful with this one that you really want *everything* in that directory in that other directory!

Comment: Thank you for providing an easy to understand example, I really appreciate it!

Comment: If needed, `shopt -u extglob` to toggle "off" (view status with `shopt extglob`).

Comment: Note that this **will not work if** you write e.g. `mv !(child1/) grandChild*` - the name of the directory to exclude must not contain the trailing slash!

Answer (score 6):

Since find does have an exclude option, use find + xargs + mv:

```
find /source/directory -name ignore-directory-name -prune -print0 | xargs -0 mv --target-directory=/target/directory
```

Note that this is almost copied from the find man page (I think using mv --target-directory is better than cpio).

Answer (score 5):

First get the names of files and folders and exclude whichever you want:

```
ls --ignore=file1 --ignore==folder1 --ignore==regular-expression1 ...
```

Then pass filtered names to `mv` as the first parameter and the second parameter will be the destination:

```
mv $(ls --ignore=file1 --ignore==folder1 --ignore==regular-expression1 ...) destination/
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it might do the job:

```
mv the-folder-you-want-to-exclude somewhere-outside-of-the-main-tree
mv the-tree where-you-want-it
mv the-excluded-folder original-location
```

(Essentially, move the excluded folder out of the larger tree to be moved.)

So, if I have `a/` and I want to exclude `a/b/c/*`:

```
mv a/b/c ../c
mv a final_destination
mkdir -p a/b
mv ../c a/b/c
```

Or something like that. Otherwise, you might be able to get `find` to help you.

Comment: And if the files you are moving are in your root? Some systems, for instance, only give user access to one directory (some cloud IDEs are a good example). Maybe someone wants to move everything to a child directory. This won't work.

Comment: As I said (six years ago), the answer doesn't describe exactly what was asked for, and it only *might* do the job. For most cases, it should work; certainly, yours is an exception to that.

Comment: You're right, it does not. But my point was not that it wasn't what was asked for, but that it in some cases would not work. My example was just a hypothetical to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 2):

rename your directory to make it hidden so the wildcard does not see it:

```
mv specific_dir .specific_dir 
mv * ../other_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

This will move all files at or below the current directory not in the ./exclude/ directory to /wherever...

```
find -E . -not -type d -and -not -regex '\./exclude/.*' -exec echo mv {} /wherever \;
```

Comment: this will ignore directory structure and copy all files in sub directories into one flat folder structure.
a/b/c/ -> /wherever
a/b.txt -> /wherever

Comment: I got `unknown predicate '-E'`

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | grep -v exclude-dir | xargs -t -I '{}' mv {} exclude-dir
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation to your code-only answer? It would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. Also, have a look here to improve appearance: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

touch apple  banana  carrot  dog  cherry

mkdir fruit

F="apple  banana  carrot  dog cherry"

mv ${F/dog/} fruit
```

# this removes 'dog' from the list F, so it remains in the 
     current directory and not moved to 'fruit'

Answer (score 0):

> Inspired by @user13747357 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612157/how-to-use-mv-command-to-move-files-except-those-in-a-specific-directory#63750717).

First you can `ls` the file and filter them by:

```
ls | egrep -v '(dir_name|file_name.ext)'
```

Then you can run the following command to move the files except the specific ones:

```
mv $(ls | egrep -v '(dir_name|file_name.ext)') target_dir
```

* Note that I tested this inside a specific directory. Cross-directory operation should be more carefully executed :)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you directory is

```
.
├── dir1
│    └── a.txt
├── dir2
│    ├── b.txt
│    └── hello.c
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt
```

and you gonna put `file1 file2 file3` into `dir2`.

you can use
`mv $(ls -p | grep -v /)  /dir2` to finish it, because

`ls -p | grep -v /` will print all files except directory in cwd.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if I want to move all files/directories - except a specified file or directory - inside "var/www/html" to a sub-folder named "my_sub_domain", then I use "mv" with the command "!(what_to_exclude)":

$ cd /var/www/html
$ mv !(my_sub_domain) my_sub_domain

To exclude more I use "|" to seperate file/directory names:

$ mv !(my_sub_domain|test1.html) my_sub_domain

Answer (score -2):

```
mv * exclude-dir
```

was the perfect solution for me