# Error in check_call() subprocess, executing 'mv' unix command: "Syntax error: '(' unexpected"

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh, travis-ci

I'm making a python script for Travis CI.

**.travis.yml**

```
...

script:
  - support/travis-build.py

...
```

The python file `travis-build.py` is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

...

check_call(r"mv !(my_project|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal) ./my_project/final_folder", shell=True)

...
```

When Travis building achieves that line, I'm getting an error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I just tried a lot of different forms to write it, but I get the same result. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

My current directory layout:

```
- my_project/final_folder/
- cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal/
- fileA
- fileB
- fileC
```

I'm trying with this command to move all the current files `fileA`, `fileB` and `fileC`, excluding  `my_project` and `cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal` folders into `./my_project/final_folder`. If I execute this command on Linux shell, I get my aim but not through check_call() command.

**Note**: I can't move the files one by one, because there are many others

I don't know which shell Travis are using by default because I don't specify it, I only know that if I write the command in my .travis.yml:

**.travis.yml**

```
...

script:
  # Here is the previous Travis code
  - mv !(my_project|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal) ./my_project/final_folder

...
```

It works. But If I use the script, it fails.

I found this command from the following issue:

[How to use 'mv' command to move files except those in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18143395/3428730)

Comment: Are you trying to do process substitution? If so, the syntax would be `$(my_project|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal)`

Comment: In which kinds of shells do you expect your syntax to work?

Comment: @Tom I didn't try it, I'll change it to prove again

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I expect it works on `sh` shell

Comment: You need to make it clear what you're trying to do because at the moment, we're only guessing. Is `my_project` a command? Do you want the output of piping it to the command `cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal` to be used as the first argument to `mv`? If not, there's no point in trying my suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the **bash** feature `extglob`, to try to exclude the files that you're specifying. You'll need to enable it in order to have it exclude the two entries you're specifying.

The python subprocess module explicitly uses `/bin/sh` when you use `shell=True`, which **doesn't** enable the use of bash features like this by default (it's a compliance thing to make it more like original `sh`).

If you want to get bash to interpret the command; you have to pass it to bash explicitly, for example using:

```
subprocess.check_call(["bash", "-O", "extglob", "-c", "mv !(my_project|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal) ./my_project/final_folder"])
```

I would not choose to do the job in this manner, though.

Comment: I so totally did not know of this bash extension. You learn something new every day ...

Comment: I felt that this is a sophisticated globbing syntax, but Googling the corresponding bash documentation is non-trivial. Now I found this document which looks quite clean and helpful: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Comment: I couldn't trivially find it through google either. But the GNU bash docs do mention it (if you know what to look for: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching )

Answer (score 0):

Let me try again: in which shell do you expect your syntax `!(...)` to work? Is it bash? Is it ksh? I have never used it, and a quick search for a corresponding bash feature led nowhere. I suspect your syntax is just *wrong*, which is what the error message is telling you. In that case, your problem is entirely independent form python and the `subprocess` module.

If a special shell you have on your system supports this syntax, you need to make sure that Python is using the same shell when invoking your command. It tells you which shell it has been using: `/bin/sh`. This is usually just a link to the real shell executable. Does it point to the same shell you have tested your command in?

Edit: the SO solution you referenced contains the solution in the comments:

> Tip: Note however that using this pattern relies on **extglob**. You can
>   enable it using shopt -s extglob (If you want extended globs to be
>   turned on by default you can add shopt -s extglob to .bashrc)

Just to demonstrate that different shells might deal with your syntax in different ways, first using bash:

```
$ !(uname)
-bash: !: event not found
```

And then, using /bin/dash:

```
$ !(uname)
Linux
```

Answer (score -1):

The argument to a `subprocess.something` method must be a list of command line arguments. Use e.g. `shlex.split()` to make the string be split into correct command line arguments:

```
import shlex, subprocess
subprocess.check_call( shlex.split("mv !(...)") )
```

EDIT:
So, the goal is to move files/directories, with the exemption of some file(s)/directory(ies). By playing around with bash, I could get it to work like this:

```
mv `ls | grep -v -e '\(exclusion1\|exclusion2\)'` my_project
```

So in your situation that would be:

```
mv `ls | grep -v -e '\(myproject\|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal\)'` my_project
```

This could go into the `subprocess.check_call(..., shell=True)` and it should do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks @haavee, I just tried it but now I receive: `mv: cannot stat '!(my_project|cmake-3.0.2-Darwin64-universal)': No such file or directory`

Comment: I'd say the "!" in there is erroneous. Probably it should be a $, for it looks like you need to substitute the output of whatever is between the '()'s. Also, the "|" pipe in there is suspicious. Exactly what should the "mv" command do?

Comment: `shell=True` is passed in, so no, the OP should **not** be splitting the command into a list. They are explicitly using shell features. `!(...)` is interpreted by the shell first before it executes the move.

Comment: Ok, then remove the "shell=True" ;-)

Comment: No, because then you cannot use shell features in your command.