# Unix Move files without matching a pattern

Tags: unix

I have a query on unix move for files not matching pattern. Example below:

Directory listing

```
 20150325
 20150326
 20150327
 20150328
 archieve
```

Now, I want to move all the files not matching 20150328 into archieve directory with a single command. Please help......

Comment: Assuming they're all in the same folder (you haven't said!) `for x in 2015* ; do if [ ! "$x" = "20150328" ] ; then mv $x archieve; fi ; done`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612157/how-to-use-mv-command-to-move-files-except-those-in-a-specific-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find with the -name parameter and the ! negation operator:

```
find . -type f ! -name 20150328 -exec mv {} archieve \;
```

The {} matches the file just found, and the escaped semi-colon terminates the exec'ed command.
To exclude multiple files, just repeat the `! -name filename` clause

Comment: This one worked .. but with some warning message like below:  mv: 0653-405 ./archieve/20150327 and archieve/20150327 are identical.
 for all the files

Comment: Also how about multiple files. I want to move all the files leaving files with 2 conditions... say .. as per above example I want to keep 20150328  and 20150327.

Comment: @Bhabani Shankar see my added sentence about multiple exclusions.  I'm not sure why you're getting warnings about identical files.,  Are all your source files in one directory with unique names?

Answer (score 1):

execute: `shopt -s extglob`
after that do: `mv !(20150328) "destination"`